# How do I prevent my Mac from autocorrecting my username?

Tags: autocorrect, auto-complete

Every time I try to login with my usual username (i.e. **g**samaras), I get a pop-up, like a suggestion from my Mac, for the word *samaras*, so unless I click on the x button, "gsamaras" will be replaced by "samaras".

How can I tell my Mac not to correct gsamaras?

Note: Formatting the laptop is not an option.

Comment: When you say "login," do you mean logging into your Mac itself or into Ask Different?

Comment: Once logged in, can you try this: Open text edit, type your name, right click  and pick "Learn Spelling". Maybe that will add it to a system wide dictionary? Also, maybe try to have it Learn Spelling from the login screen?

Comment: @joels I don't believe it's a system dictionary, but rather a user-specific one (it's inside ~/Library). However, if this need only apply to one user account, that should probably suffice.

Comment: I mean when logging into my email for example, sorry! @joels that did the trick, I suggest you post an answer! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type your name, right click and pick "Learn Spelling".

Answer (score 1):

You can add the word to your dictionary or you can disable auto correct. Go up to Edit -> Spelling and Grammar, then untick Correct Spelling Automatically.